# What is needed to run Traefik main reverse-proxy under a subdomain?

Tags: dns, subdomain, reverse-proxy, traefik

I have successfully setup Traefik under a top-level domain such as `example.com`, which is used as a main reverse proxy in docker-swarm with multiple containers/stacks. This way, I could automatically point traefik to subdomains received from docker containerized services, e.g. `service1.example.com`, `service2.example.com` etc.

My question is, would such a setup also work if I run traefik in a subdomain, e.g. `app.example.com`, where `example.com` is hosted on a completely separate server not managed by traefik? I want my containers to be reachable similarly in those subdomains, e.g. `service1.app.example.com`, `service2.app.example.com`, wherein subdomains (`service1`, `service2`) are managed by traefik running at `app.example.com`.

I know that I needed a DNS A record to point to my traefik-instance in example 1, can I do something similar with a subdomain or would this work differently?

Many thanks for hints!

Comment: Yes, I should have perhaps asked this on Serverfault, but now the question is answered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work without a problem, as long as your domain provider doesn't restrict this.

You will have an `A` record with `*.app` and point it to the `Traefik` server ip

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this answer! Let me clarify my reason to request info beforehand: we want to deploy a web app (that we're currently running in a top domain) in a subdomain of an official city website (e.g. `app.city.ca.gov`). Before approaching the city, I'd like to make sure that such an approach would work. Simply as that, answer awarded! :)